# I can't find the contact after I saved them on my IPhone 5S,

Tags: iphone

I can't find the contact after I saved them on my IPhone 5S, I have searched for the name after I saved the number but couldn't find it, I don't know how to solve this issue I can't even find it in the Apps like Whats App.. It sounds like the contacts disappear?

Comment: Do you mean a specific contact or the app named `Contacts'?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Contacts. Upper Left hand corner, tap "Groups". You may have more than one account apart from your iCloud account, like Gmail. In this case, it might be that only one account is checked so just check all accounts including your iCloud account.